# Android: Detect switch from Mobile to WiFi for WebSocket connection

Tags: android, mobile, websocket, wifi

I have an app that is constantly connected to a server via WebSocket.

I noticed that when the connection is first established via the Mobile network (due to lack of WiFi) and I later connect the device to a WiFi network, the WebSocket connection will still communicate over the Mobile network.

How do I detect that such a situation occurred so that I explicitly perform a reconnect to the server?

I know that I can listen to `WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION / SupplicantState.COMPLETED` in order to trigger a reconnect, but I would like to do this only if I am sure that there is currently a WebSocket connection that is using the mobile network. How can I query such a TCP connection for which network it is using?

I also noticed that if I reconnect immediately as a response to `WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION / SupplicantState.COMPLETED` it seems that it is still thinking that Mobile is the preferred channel. As if it takes a couple of seconds for everything to realize that it can use WiFi for connecting. Does anyone have more knowledge about this?

Comment: Android uses Wifi as preference and after mobile data. You can try to close the WebSocketand reopen and it maybe it conect via WIFI.

Comment: @RolandoCorratgeNieves I am aware of this. I want to detect when such a situation where I should reconnect occurs. And I only want to trigger that specific reconnect when an active WebSocket connection exists over mobile.